# In Java, get the style property used value or computed value of an element

Tags: java, html, css

Is there any Java API which would take a html document and a css document as input and allow me to ask: give me the used value for property x for element with id y? 
(Computed value would also be fine but used value even better).

(I would like to use a small subset of CSS2.1 as input to style an excel sheet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is any library like that but in order to achieve solution to your problem you can use a CSS Parser [Simple API For CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/SAC/Overview.en.html) has many implementation, then you can do a query the parsed content for query. If you want to parse HTML also in Java then you can use apache HTML parser. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I briefly looked into CSS Parser. However, it seems it is mainly parsing a CSS file and does not provide computation of style on a specific element in a DOM tree. For example, say I style a background color with inherit on an element with id "x", then in the DOM tree say I have a child element to "x" without styling. In that case that child will inherit from element with id "x". Could CSS Parser and apache HTML parser be used together to provide me also with the computed value? Thanks.

Comment: yes you are correct CSS Parser will parse your css file, once you have the DOM tree you can [use](http://jsoup.org/) which provides nice selectors to fetch you nodes in that way you can determine the css for almost every element.

Comment: "you can determine the css for almost every element", how could I do that? Afaik, jsoup does not give the computed css values for the elements. Any styling I would get would be specific styling on an element (as opposed to inherited or computed).

Comment: once you have elements just do a selector query and check in the CSS DOM what all properties are defined for that given CSS element.

Comment: mprabhat, I am sorry but that does not solve the problem of getting the computed/used css value.

Comment: The computed value will be the custom implementation something like  myComputedValue = myValue + inheritedValueFromParent ( since we are also going to parse HTML parent child relationship will be maintained.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not that simple. The rules are more involved than that, which is why I first wanted to see if there was something which would do this for me. Nevertheless, if I would have to do implement my own computation of the values, CSS Parser is still useful. Thanks for your help.